# If $R$ is an integral domain and $p\in R$ then $p$ is prime in $R[x]$ if and only if $p$ is prime in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am able to prove that $p \in R[x]$ prime implies $p$ is prime in $R$ since $R \subset R[x]$. I am having trouble proving the other implication though, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One way is to show that $(R/p)[X] \cong R[X]/p$, then ask when either side is an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the fact that a ring $S$ is an integral domain if and only if $S[X]$ is. To see the only if side, if $f(X) = \sum_{i=0}^na_iX^i$ and $g(X) = \sum_{i=0}^mb_iX^i$, with $a_n,b_m\ne0$, then $$f(X)g(X) =\sum_{i,j}a_ib_jX^{i+j}=0\implies a_nb_m=0\implies a_n = 0\text{ or }b_m = 0.$$

Take $S$ to be $(R/(p))[X]$, and show that this is isomorphic to $R[X]/(p)$.